# How to use pyspark dataframes instead of pandas dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert pandas transformation to pyspark implementation. The issue I am getting is that I am not able to find a suitable implementation of dictionary in pyspark. Therefore I would like to use pyspark dataframe for my trasnformation.

I am trying to calculate trasition_states from a df_agg (spark dataframe ) and channel_list ( list of unique channels in dataframe ).

Some of the opertaion that is done using pandas is shown in the below code. I am looking for some implementation of using pyspark datafrmae instead of pandas to acheive the transformations.

```
    def transitions(df_agg, channel_list):
        '''
        Purpose: Calculate transition count for each channel pair
        Inputs:
        1. df_agg: spark dataframe with channel path
        2. channel_list: list of unique channels in dataframe
        Output:
        transition_states: Dictionary with key as channel transition and value as count
        '''
        df_agg2 = df_agg.select('path_string', 'count_values')
        trans = df_agg2.toPandas().set_index('path_string').to_dict()['count_values']
        transition_states = {x + ' > ' + y: 0 for x in channel_list for y in channel_list}
        for k in trans.keys():
            transition_states[k] = trans[k]
        return transition_states

    trans = transitions(df_agg, channel_list)
```

This works fine to get the transitions using pandas. It works fine for few thousand rows. But I have some million rows to handle and pandas seems to be very slow in that.

How to optimise it using pyspark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to simulate the problem with some test data.

```
import pandas as pd 
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import  col, concat_ws
df_agg = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/stacktest-1.csv", header = True)
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
channel_list_df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, StringType())
df_agg.show()

+-----------+------------+
|path_string|count_values|
+-----------+------------+
|      a > b|           2|
|      a > c|           3|
|      b > c|           5|
|      c > a|          10|
+-----------+------------+
```

I applied the datasets to the pandas' function that you have provided

```
def transitions(df_agg, channel_list):
  df_agg2 = df_agg.select('path_string', 'count_values')
  trans = df_agg2.toPandas().set_index('path_string').to_dict()['count_values']
  transition_states = {x + ' > ' + y: 0 for x in channel_list for y in channel_list}
  for k in trans.keys():
    transition_states[k] = trans[k]
  return transition_states  

trans = transitions(df_agg, mylist)
print(trans)

{'a > a': 0, 'a > b': '2', 'a > c': '3', 'b > a': 0, 'b > b': 0, 'b > c': '5', 'c > a': '10', 'c > b': 0, 'c > c': 0}
```

This is the pyspark equivalent code for the pandas' function.

```
newColumns = ["value_1", "value_2"]
inter=channel_list_df.crossJoin(channel_list_df).toDF(*newColumns).withColumn('testColumn',concat_ws(' > ',col('value_1'), col('value_2'))).select(col('testColumn'))
inter.join(df_agg, inter.testColumn == df_agg.path_string ,how='left').select(col('testColumn'), col('count_values')).na.fill(value = '0', subset=["count_values"]).show()
```

Below is the result from the pyspark program

```
+----------+------------+
|testColumn|count_values|
+----------+------------+
|     a > a|           0|
|     a > b|           2|
|     a > c|           3|
|     b > a|           0|
|     b > b|           0|
|     b > c|           5|
|     c > a|          10|
|     c > b|           0|
|     c > c|           0|
+----------+------------+
```